# advice on re-connecting 2" PVC piping

Tags: joints

A few years ago in a pinch with a failing septic system I diverted some grey water to a reed bed (see elbow marked "remove...". Unfortunately although it works, I painted myself into a corner
[image: a not-great piping job]

The green lines show where the pipes used to connect up, and where I need to reconnect them. Anything below the red line belongs to the reed-bed I need to decommission. I see now that the way I did it makes re-connecting (per green lines) trickier than it needed to be.

I might be able to hack it, but would appreciate if there's experienced advice on the best approach.

The domed cap and the elbow connected to the wye/tee are glued (short pieced of pipe inside the female ends.) There's not a lot of movement on any of these 2" Sch. 40 pipes, so I suspect flexible couplings will be part of the solution.

Question: suppose I cut 2 places marked in blue - is it feasible to grind out the glued remnants of pipe inside the fittings to restore the female connectors

- joint between wye/tee and elbow (on the left)
- joint between the domed cap and the wye it's connected to)

all of the pipes shown are gravity feed, so no pressure anywhere

[image]

Comment: use a union connector ... or expansion connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you are seeking is typically known as a hub saver or socket saver - they come from inexpensive homeowner versions on up to expensive and nicer professional plumber versions.

The more typical approach with access, *rather than a hub with a pipe in it inside a hole in a wall,* is to cut out until you can use couplings and new fittings to replace the stuff glued with no space.

Comment: thanks - "cut out until you can use couplings and new fittings" - makes sense, yes. Downstream of the domed-cap things get ugly fast - the cap is on a 4" wye on a black water line I'd rather not mess with. The hub/socket saver recommendation will help me avoid that